# Find user running windows process

Tags: windows-7, process

How can I see which user is running sqlserver process in a windows 7 machine? I need to know this in order to change some permissions. I opened the task manager but the list is almost empty, maybe because I'am on a virtual machine, do I have a command line option? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Applications` tab of task manager will only show desktop applications.  You should be able to see the SQL Server process in the `Processes` tab.  Make sure you click the `Show Processes from All Users` button at the bottom of the task manager screen.

The other way do do this is to see what user is defined in the service properties:

1. Start, then type "Services" in the search box, and choose `Services` from the results
2. Find the SQL Server service, and right-click and choose properties
3. Go to the `Log On` tab and you will see that SQL Server is either running as system, or a specific account.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it from the command line, here is a quick guide:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/display-a-list-of-started-services-from-the-command-line-windows/

Comment: :( unfortunately this doesn't give me the name of the user running the process

Comment: Hmmm you can try installing an application to help you,
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653